# Does SQLAlchemy reopen session after commit?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm wondering, can SQLAlchemy reopen session after calling session.commit()? The following code sometimes (not always, most of the time there are no errors) gives an error `ProgrammingError('(ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'dbname.tmp_table' doesn't exist")`. Very simplified code, but it should show the sequence of actions:

```
with create_session() as session:
    session.execute("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS dbname.tmp_table")
    session.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dbname.tmp_table (field list)")
    session.commit()
    while loop_condition is valid:
        # This line gives accidentally errors
        session.execute("INSERT INTO dbname.tmp_table (fields) SELECT ...")
        # A couple of another data manipulations on DB server
        ...
        session.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE dbname.tmp_table")
        session.commit()
    session.execute("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS dbname.tmp_table")
    session.commit()
```

I use sqlalchemy with mysql 5.5 and use `TEMPORARY TABLE` of mysql to cache some aggregation results for a transaction. I know that temp table is only accessible for the session where it was created. So my only suggestion is that SQLALchemy's session sometimes reopens actual MySQL's session after commits. Is it possible or there is another, correct explanation?

Comment: You probably simplified your code too much, and get somewhere a new session instantiated where you don't want to. The example is perfectly fine in that regard - Nobody can  recreate the problem with that code.

Comment: No, I didn't miss new session creation :) It Is the key point - there are no new sessions, no commits (except those I've shown), all operations are in one session created in the `with` clause. I can't reproduce the problem even by myself on my local host. It appears only in production environment, and it is not permanent, as I mentioned above. More details: the entire operation takes about 15-20 seconds and there are about 18 iterations in the loop.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you've got connectivity problems? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#dealing-with-disconnects

Comment: Yes, most likely it is caused by a connectivity problem. But I didn't see errors about dropped connections or something else. Session is alive and it talks to DB server. I've solved my problem by moving creation of temp table into one transaction with data manipulations (under `while` loop). But it is still interesting why I got that errors.